# freeze other function use while(true) in php when need sse

Tags: php, laravel, websocket, server-sent-events

hi I need sse use in my code and it need while(true) run so when I use it other function does not work I need work function in same time

```
        while (true) {
            echo $this->event->fill();
            ob_flush();
            flush();
            if (connection_aborted()) {
                return;
            }
            sleep($interval);
        }
```

this is my loop function

```
  public function index(Request $request)
    {
//do something
}
```

I run loop function first and run index function after this but this freeze  until loop function  run

Comment: I really don't understand what you are trying to do here, but `while(true)` is a recipe for problems. Never create an endless loop...

Comment: I have to use Because I want to have a app similar to this [link](https://chrisblackwell.me/server-sent-events-using-laravel-vue/) or this one [link2](https://blog.devgenius.io/create-notification-laravel-webapp-with-sse-1fadd509c33b)

Comment: No, you don't have to use that, ever! There is always a good way of solving it. An endless loop is never the solution to any problem. You cannot let a PHP function run endlessly, there is a max_execution_time (thank god)

Comment: what is your solution ? I need use sse in my app add sse need while(true) , when I use this while other function do not work

Comment: It's not clear what exactly you are trying to do, so I cannot give you the solution. But you never "need" `while(true)` If it is an ajax call from your vue for example, you can handle it in your vue app.

Comment: I try create real time project but I not want use websocket because In the websocket on Android, the connection is cut off quickly so ajax  and websocket  is not helpful

Comment: @GertB. Using a `while(true)` loop *is* the correct way to write a server-events handler loop. It's purpose in life is to run forever... until the client disconnects. At that point the web server process will kill the PHP process.

Comment: @GertB. as You wrote "You really don't understand" please read more about SSE (server-side events) with official example on MDN (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Server-sent_events/Using_server-sent_events), `if (connection_aborted()) { break; }` quits from loop after client disconnect.

Answer (score 0):

> I run loop function first and run index function after this...

You cannot run an infinite loop and then run a function afterwards. :-)

I think you are saying you want `index()` to be called at regular intervals, while it is handling the SSE loop? If your sleep `$interval` was, say, 1 second, and you want `index()` called every 5 seconds, you could do it like this:

```
for($i=0;;$i++){
     echo $this->event->fill();
     ob_flush();
     flush();
     if (connection_aborted()) {
        return;
     }
     sleep($interval);
    if($i % 5 == 0)index(???);
}
```

By the way, `for(;;){...}` is another way to write a `while(true){...}` infinite loop.

I don't know where your `$request` argument came from, so I've just shown that as `???` above.

Taking a step back, and trying to guess what `index($request)` might be doing, make sure you understand that there is one SSE process running for every single client that is connected. It is a dedicated process, and it also does not receive any further information from the client while running. I.e. if `index()` is creating an index for use by all clients it belongs in another process, running in parallel.

Comment: In fact, I want this **while** function run That the connection of **SSE** is established, and after the connection, if a person chooses another route, that route will be executed and will not wait for the end of the first one to run.

Comment: @hh You need two processes for the client "choosing another route". SSE is a dedicated process for event pushing. It cannot *directly* react to anything the user does after it has been started. (It can indirectly react, though: you could have user actions modify data in the database that the SSE process is regularly polling, for instance.)

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are using php built-in server as your web server (if you used **php artisan serve** for running your laravel project it is the case).  [Here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.webserver.php) it says:

> The web server runs only one single-threaded process, so PHP applications will stall if a request is blocked

That simply means you can't implement Server-sent events with this web server.

You need to use another web server (get rid of **php artisan serve**).

Comment: OP uses output buffer, which can control the output display based on the PHP logic. It does not require multi-thread processes.

Comment: @Raptor, the problem with the OP code is that he wants to handle two requests at the same time and it cannot be done with php built-in web server, see this: https://pretagteam.com/question/max-concurrent-connections-for-phps-built-in-development-server